# Multiprocessing code behaves differently when commenting out one print statement

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This is my code:

```
from random import random
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
import time


def new(shared_queue):
    print('Consumer: Running', flush=True)
    while shared_queue.qsize() > 0:
        shared_queue.get()
        print(shared_queue.qsize())
    print('Consumer: Done', flush=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()

    # Init Queue
    queue = Queue()
    for _ in range(50000):
        # generate a value
        value = random()
        # add to the queue
        queue.put(value)

    print('Init Queue size', queue.qsize())

    p0 = Process(target=new, args=(queue,))
    p0.start()
    p1 = Process(target=new, args=(queue,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=new, args=(queue,))
    p2.start()

    p0.join()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print("Done in --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

When I run this, I get the result I expect:

```
Consumer: Done
Consumer: Done
Consumer: Done
Done in --- 5.304457664489746 seconds ---
```

However, when I only comment out the line

```
print(shared_queue.qsize())
```

I only get this result:

```
Init Queue size 50000
Consumer: Running
Consumer: Running
Consumer: Running
Consumer: Done
```

Why don't I see the other `Consumer: Done` lines and the
`Done in --- xxx seconds ---`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `get` is too fast and `print` too slow. If the consumers get elements super fast may occur that one consumer, let's say `p1` checks `shared_queue.qsize() > 0` and by the time `p1`arrives to `shared_queue.get()` other consumer has called `shared_queue.get()`for the last element.

If your example has not concurrent producers and consumers (if your queue is fully defined by the time the first consumer starts) instead of use `timeout` as [AhmedAEK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15649230) suggested, you can use `shared_queue.get(block=False)`, which will raise and exception that you will have to catch as AhmedAEK showed:

```
def new(shared_queue):
    print('Consumer : Running', flush=True)
    while shared_queue.qsize() > 0:
        try:
            shared_queue.get(block=False)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        # print(shared_queue.qsize())
    print('Consumer : Done', flush=True)
```

Comment: you should replace `break` with `continue`, as `get(block=False)` can raise an `Empty` error if two processes try to pull data from it at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

there is a finite time in microsecond between checking `shared_queue.qsize() > 0` and executing `shared_queue.get()`, in this small time another process could have grabbed the last item off the queue so when this process calls `get()`, it is now trying to get an item from an empty queue which is a blocking action, and your application will hang.

the print slows the process down enough that it "seems" to work, but this is only by pure luck, the wrost bug is the bug that doesn't appear in testing.

a good way to handle this is to set a timeout on the `shared_queue.get(timeout=0.01)` so that the child won't be stuck waiting on an empty queue, there are obviously other ways like puting a termination command on the queue itself after all the work is sent.

with the added timeout the next code is guaranteed to work correctly every time.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
import time
from random import random
import queue

def new(shared_queue):
    print('Consumer: Running', flush=True)
    while shared_queue.qsize() > 0:
        try:
            shared_queue.get(timeout=0.01)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
    print('Consumer: Done', flush=True)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()

    # Init Queue
    queue = Queue()
    for _ in range(50000):
        # generate a value
        value = random()
        # add to the queue
        queue.put(value)

    print('Init Queue size', queue.qsize())

    p0 = Process(target=new, args=(queue,))
    p0.start()
    p1 = Process(target=new, args=(queue,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=new, args=(queue,))
    p2.start()

    p0.join()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print("Done in --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```